# Complex search and replace in VSCode with calculation

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to search and replace a part of code in a lot of files. The code is:

```
    width = ((29.7 / 2.54) * x),
    height = ((21 / 2.54) * y))
```

where x and y are different floating point numbers. This is in my project about 250 times with different xs ans ys (not the best, I know, but it is what it is :)). I want to divide all xs and ys by `1.5`. Is there an easy way to do this using `VSCode`s search in folder?
Of course, I could simply replace `width = ((29.7 / 2.54)` with `width = ((29.7 / 2.54) * (1 / 1.5)` (and the same for `height`), but then the code would get even longer. Is there a way to change the actual xs and ys using regex and calculations?

Comment: best to write a conversion function from A4-cm to A4-inch, but you can also use an extension I wrote [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen), see the examples related to SVG number conversion.

Comment: So would changing `x` to `x / 1.5` work for you, and same for the `y`'s?

Comment: What kind of files are these? Which programming language?